# rails partial rendering html does not run javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am calling a partial from controller file but the javascript inside the partial is not executing . The partial is of .html.erb format.

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var eventName = typeof(Turbolinks) !== 'undefined' ? 'page:change' : 'DOMContentLoaded';

    document.addEventListener(eventName, function() {
      console.log("hello");


      <% if flash[:notice] %>
        ShopifyApp.flashNotice("<%= escape_javascript flash[:notice].html_safe %>");
      <% end %>

      <% if flash[:error] %>
        ShopifyApp.flashError("<%= escape_javascript flash[:error].html_safe %>");
      <% end %>
    });
  </script>
<% end %>
```

is the code for partial

```
 respond_to do |format| 
    if @timer.save



      flash[:notice]="updated"
      format.html{render :partial => "layouts/flash_messages", :locals => {:flash => flash}}





    else
        flash[:error]="error"
      format.html{render :partial => "layouts/flash_messages", :locals => {:flash => flash}}
    end
```

is the controller code .

Comment: That partial doesn't render anything, it just adds the javascript to the `:javascript` content store. Usually this `content_for` technique has a corresponding `<%= yield :javascript %>` or `<%= content_for :javascript %>` elsewhere in a layout.

Comment: Thanks Aaron Breckenridge going to try yeild :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to render Javascript in rails use below method.

Controller Code looks like:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to @user }
    format.js
  end
end
```

template this code going to render will look like.

filename:  create.js.erb

```
 $("#someidname").html("<%= @user.email %>");
```

Note @user is also available here. you can render other partial also like:

```
$("#someit").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('users/email')) %>");
```

Also, make sure you are sending ajax request.